# How i can get quantity of not self model records on controller ? RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Ruby on Rails development and I have a problem:
I've 2 controllers and one model

```
Controllers:
Main, Users
Model: 
User
```

I need to get the quantity of records of user model in my `MainController`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
  #..other actions
end
```

Now the `index.html.erb` view will be rendered, and you can show there the quantity. `User` is a model. Read this [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) to understand Rails MVC at a glance.

In your view *app/views/users/index.html.erb*, suppose you put the below

```
<h1>Users quantity is <%= @users.size %></h1>
```

Comment: So i have User object on my namespace in Main controller?

Answer (score 1):

Collections of object in rails have similar methods with arrays, and you can get quantity of collection's element use method **size**.

For example if you get all objects form db, you can get quantity of them just wrote

**For example**

`@object = YourModel.all
quantity = @object.size`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to grab only the quantify of the records of a User model, then you might want to do the following:

`User.count`